# Impedance matrix of a transmission line

Tags: power, transmission-line, mutual-inductance

I'm studying power systems and this question came up: if there are two transmission lines in series and I know the impedance matrix of each one (Zp is self-impedance and Zm is mutual impedance):

[image]

[image]

Can I afirm that the impedance matrix of these two lines in series is:[image] ?

Or should I just add the self-impedances and keep the mutual impedances as Zm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The impedance of two identical lines in series is exactly the same as one of those identical lines.

Comment: Why does that happen? And what if they are not identical?

Comment: If they are not identical then you will get reflections at the discontinuity.